# Генератор случайных вещественных чисел в заданном диапазоне

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

Как написать правильный генератор вещественных чисел (в промежутке от `а` до `b` — которые вводит пользователь)? Числа должны содержать 2 знака после запятой.

Comment: Я правильно понял? rand()% ((100*b-100*a)+100*a)/100

Comment: @Suvitruf: как закрытие этого вопроса поможет будущим посетителям из гугла с похожей проблемой? Как по-вашему это согласуется с миссией сайта? [Работа за автора](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/231/23044)

Comment: @jfs а вы всё ещё не бросили попытки переманить меня на светлую сторону)

Answer (score 3):

"Правильность" в контексте случайных вещественных чисел на компьютере — это неочевидная вещь. Оба понятия реализуются с привлечением компромиссов, которые не всегда приемлимы — в разных ситуациях разные решения могут быть "правильными".

К примеру, чтобы случайно выбрать число с плавающей точкой в диапазоне `[a, b]`, можно `uniform_real_distribution<>` использовать:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  // read two real numbers
  double a, b;
  if (!(std::cin >> a >> b))
    std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  // generate random number in [a, b] range
  std::random_device rd; // used to generate a seed
  std::mt19937 generator(rd());
  double nextafter_b = std::nextafter(b, std::numeric_limits<decltype(b)>::max());
  std::uniform_real_distribution<> distr(a, nextafter_b);
  double r = distr(generator);

  // output with 2 decimal points
  std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << r;
}
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/5yuURw):

```
$ c++ -std=c++11 uniform_real.cc -o uniform_real
$ echo 1.2345 6.789 | ./uniform_real
4.39
```

Если важно, чтобы рассматривались только 2 знака после запятой, можно рубли в целые копейки превратить и использовать [`randint()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/randint), чтобы выбрать случайное целое в диапазоне `[100*a, 100*b]`:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <experimental/random>

using std::experimental::randint;

int main()
{
  // read two numbers specified with 2 decimal places
  std::string a, b;
  if (!(std::cin >> a >> b))
    std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  // "1.23" -> Int(123)
  auto two_places = [](std::string s) -> long long {
    s += "00"; // pad with zeros for 1. -> 100 case
    auto i = s.find('.');
    if (i != std::string::npos) { // found decimal point
      s = s.substr(0, i) + s.substr(i+1, 2); // drop decimal point
    }
    return std::stoll(s);
  };
  long long r = randint(two_places(a), two_places(b));
  unsigned long long ur = std::abs(r);
  std::cout << (r < 0 ? "-" : "")
            << (ur / 100) << '.'
            << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << (ur % 100u)
            << std::endl;
}
```

Ввод и результаты аналогичны предыдущему примеру. За исключением [ввода](https://ideone.com/NqCsB5), когда [double не хватает точности](https://ideone.com/RbmMjj).

Вместо `randint()` можно использовать `uniform_int_distribution<>` по аналогии с решением, использующим `uniform_real_distribution<>` выше.

Многие тонкие места не упомянуты. К примеру, вот обсуждение как правильно инициализировать mt19937 генератор: [How to succinctly, portably, and thoroughly seed the mt19937 PRNG?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45069219/4279)