# ГПСЧ с помощью Mersenne twister (диапазон значений)

Tags: c++, криптография, генерация-случайных-данных

Добрый день, друзья. Подскажите, пожалуйста, алгоритм применения вихря Мерсенна в заданном диапазоне значений (н-р 1-100), можно и реализацию на c++, если таковая имеется.

Comment: В стандартной библиотеке C++ имеется готовый генератор: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Генератор случайных вещественных чисел в заданном диапазоне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/746324/%d0%93%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5)